# Codeigniter Active Record issue (where and multiple 'AND' 'OR')

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

could somebody tell me how to generate the following query with codeigniter active record?

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_admins` WHERE (`email`='ci@php.net' OR `uname`='user') AND `upass`='SecretePass';
```

> not writing the query,
>   I mean passing different values through arrays...
>   or CI Active Record

thank you

Comment: Have you read the user guide and tried something out. It's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this in a few ways.  First, I am assuming you are passing in an array to the model function and that array is `$filters`.

**Option One**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_admins');
$this->db->where('email', $filters["email"]);
$this->db->or_where('uname', $filters["email"]); 
$this->db->where('upass', $filters["password"]);
```

**Option Two**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_admins');
$this->db->where("(email = '$filters["email"]' OR uname = '$filters["email"]') AND upass = '$filters["password"]'");
```

I did not test, so you may need to adjust the variables in option two's where a bit.  But that is fairly close to what you want.

Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870583/codeigniter-active-record-where-or-where) of a similar Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

finally I write it this way...

```
$conditions = '(`col1`="'.$var1.'" OR `col2`="'.$var1.'") AND `col3`="'.$var2.'"';          
 $query = $this->db->get_where('table',$conditions);
$result = $query->result();
```

And it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group_start()` and `group_end()` functionality (from active record) for grouping the relevant where clauses in separate groups. Here is the example of the syntax:

```
$query= $this->db->select('*')
        ->group_start()
        ->or_like($likeColumns)
        ->group_end()
        ->where($whereColumn, $whereValue)
        ->get($table);
```